# How to Image Crop And upload to Folder And Save Name in database Using Ajax And Jquery In Php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I want to crop And rezize Image and Upload In Folder For user registration and profile updations.Upload and Crop Image using PHP and jQuery. HTML Form with Image Upload Option with JQuery Croppie plugin or Image crop with PHP Script.

Comment: What is the problem with your current attempt(s)/source code?

Comment: please check this tutorial https://phppot.com/php/upload-and-crop-image-using-php-and-jquery/